# Resonant Transformer / Resonant Inductive Coupling

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, resonance, inductive, coupling

I´m trying to build a resonant transformer (or a resonant inductive coupler, I don´t know if the names fit to the topology I´m showing, anyway). The idea is to develop a high voltage on a capacitor. However, at the same time, I want a 50 ohms input impedance.

I did some research and I found [this article](http://datamac.phys.yorku.ca/papers/mok_CJP_2006.pdf), which is quite complete I would say.

I started playing with LTspice and trying to simulate a "double resonant" transformer for such capacitor. I took the values of a wideband balun/transformer from Coilcraft (WBC4-1TL):

[image]

The idea is to create the same resonance at a certain frequency in both sides of the transformer (the capacitor on the primary side has a value depending on the impedance ratio of the transformer, in this case is 4 times higher than the capacitor in the secondary side). And I obtained this:

[image]

I don´t have experience with this particular topology. However, my intuition says that these results are completely unrealistic and I´m missing something.

Are this results reasonable? Which would be the best way to probe the voltage over the capacitor (since in theory it´s "floating")?.

I would appreciate if you have any reference/book to share about this subject.

Comment: You do have to specify k and a load R , right? Or at least Q or BW and fo

Comment: As Tony says you need to specify k and it should be less than 1 so the secondary is only loosely coupled.

Comment: You do have to specify k and a load R , right? Or at least Q or BW and fo. Look up "double tuned IF filter 10.7MHz" each slug tunes a separate pole but also affected by the k factor as they can both spread apart or come together , modelled by a 3rd mutual inductance as a function of k and Lp

Comment: @lucas please ask a question, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys.
The aim is to develop a high voltage across the capacitor (which is 3pF). The resonance frequency f0 is obtained by the combination of that capacitance with L1 (36 uH) (approx. 15 MHz). L1 is the inductance of the second wiring in the transformer (according to the datasheet).

Comment: Since this is not an energy transfer application (it´s just to develop a high voltage on the capacitor) I don´t know if would be appropriate to talk about a "load" (the "load" is the capacitor). The Q factor is defined by the DCRs.

Comment: My motto is **You cannot design anything without "specs"**  and with good specs you can design anything  . what is mutual inductance range, fo and BW?  My suggestion is k=0.9 fo=10.7MHz, BW = 180 kHz Now do some home work and compute M(uH)

Comment: BTW you buy these filters for < $1

Comment: *I want a 50 ohms input impedance* - the results you got point to the impedance being purely capacitive so, of course, the results are not reasonable.